# Database error connection intermittently

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, apache

I have an issue with a Wordpress project when I use [Woorank](http://www.woorank.com).

The whole site works perfect, but when submit the URL to Woorank, it shows an "Error connecting to database". And then, if I try to access normally from browser, I'm also getting the same error. This happens until I restart mysql (`service mysql restart`), or reload the main page with administrator user, when the site works right again.

Thinking that it should be a WP problem, I disabled all plugins, change theme, `.htaccess` directives, check `wp-config.php`, ... but the error still appears.

The project is sited in a VPS with a few more projects that aren't affected by this issue.
I recently installed Nginx as proxy, but the issue was also there before.

I suppose that this issue is due to many connections at a time, because I'm not able to reproduce it without using Woorank.

The mysql logs after submitting the Woorank form:

```
140811 17:50:54 [Warning] Using unique option prefix myisam-recover instead of myisam-recover-options is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.
140811 17:50:54 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
140811 17:50:54 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
140811 17:50:54 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
140811 17:50:54 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3.4
140811 17:50:54 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
140811 17:50:54 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
140811 17:50:54 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
InnoDB: Log scan progressed past the checkpoint lsn 938907976
140811 17:50:54  InnoDB: Database was not shut down normally!
InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages from the doublewrite
InnoDB: buffer...
InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 938908419
140811 17:50:54  InnoDB: Starting an apply batch of log records to the database...
InnoDB: Progress in percents: 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99
InnoDB: Apply batch completed
140811 17:50:54  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
140811 17:50:55 InnoDB: 5.5.38 started; log sequence number 938908419
140811 17:50:55 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '127.0.0.1'; port: 3306
140811 17:50:55 [Note]   - '127.0.0.1' resolves to '127.0.0.1';
140811 17:50:55 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '127.0.0.1'.
140811 17:50:55 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
140811 17:50:55 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
```

Logs for Apache2:

```
[Mon Aug 11 17:50:25.136960 2014] [:error] [pid 11656] [client 127.0.0.1:46584] Error Lost connection to MySQL server during query de la base de datos de WordPress para la consulta select val from bio_wfConfig where name='liveTrafficEnabled' realizada por require('wp-blog-header.php'), require_once('wp-load.php'), require_once('wp-config.php'), require_once('wp-settings.php'), do_action('init'), call_user_func_array, wordfence::initAction, wfConfig::liveTrafficEnabled, wfConfig::get, wfConfig::loadFromDiskCache, wfDB->querySingle
[Mon Aug 11 17:50:25.141243 2014] [:error] [pid 11173] [client 127.0.0.1:46589] Error Lost connection to MySQL server during query de la base de datos de WordPress para la consulta SELECT t.*, tt.* FROM bio_terms AS t INNER JOIN bio_term_taxonomy AS tt ON t.term_id = tt.term_id WHERE tt.taxonomy = 'category' AND t.slug = 'biomedicina' LIMIT 1 realizada por require('wp-blog-header.php'), wp, WP->main, WP->query_posts, WP_Query->query, WP_Query->get_posts, get_term_by
[Mon Aug 11 17:50:25.191699 2014] [:error] [pid 11644] [client 127.0.0.1:46578] Error Lost connection to MySQL server during query de la base de datos de WordPress para la consulta \n\t\tSELECT ID, post_name, post_parent, post_type\n\t\tFROM bio_posts\n\t\tWHERE post_name IN ('news')\n\t\tAND post_type IN ('page','attachment')\n\t realizada por require('wp-blog-header.php'), wp, WP->main, WP->parse_request, get_page_by_path
[Mon Aug 11 17:50:25.195749 2014] [:error] [pid 11652] [client 127.0.0.1:46582] Error Lost connection to MySQL server during query de la base de datos de WordPress para la consulta SELECT option_value FROM bio_options WHERE option_name = 'jetpack_portfolio' LIMIT 1 realizada por require('wp-blog-header.php'), require_once('wp-load.php'), require_once('wp-config.php'), require_once('wp-settings.php'), do_action('init'), call_user_func_array, Jetpack_Portfolio::init, Jetpack_Portfolio->__construct, get_option
[Mon Aug 11 17:50:25.201487 2014] [:error] [pid 11668] [client 127.0.0.1:46587] Error Lost connection to MySQL server during query de la base de datos de WordPress para la consulta select val from bio_wfConfig where name='liveTrafficEnabled' realizada por require('wp-blog-header.php'), require_once('wp-load.php'), require_once('wp-config.php'), require_once('wp-settings.php'), do_action('init'), call_user_func_array, wordfence::initAction, wfConfig::liveTrafficEnabled, wfConfig::get, wfConfig::loadFromDiskCache, wfDB->querySingle
[Mon Aug 11 17:50:25.212494 2014] [:error] [pid 11148] [client 127.0.0.1:46594] Error Lost connection to MySQL server during query de la base de datos de WordPress para la consulta select val from bio_wfConfig where name='liveTrafficEnabled' realizada por require('wp-blog-header.php'), require_once('wp-load.php'), require_once('wp-config.php'), require_once('wp-settings.php'), do_action('init'), call_user_func_array, wordfence::initAction, wfConfig::liveTrafficEnabled, wfConfig::get, wfConfig::loadFromDiskCache, wfDB->querySingle
[Mon Aug 11 17:50:25.214185 2014] [:error] [pid 11110] [client 127.0.0.1:46586] Error Lost connection to MySQL server during query de la base de datos de WordPress para la consulta SELECT option_value FROM bio_options WHERE option_name = 'wpseo_flush_rewrite' LIMIT 1 realizada por require('wp-blog-header.php'), require_once('wp-load.php'), require_once('wp-config.php'), require_once('wp-settings.php'), do_action('init'), call_user_func_array, WPSEO_Rewrite->flush, get_option
[Mon Aug 11 17:50:25.982309 2014] [:error] [pid 11638] [client 127.0.0.1:46618] Error Lost connection to MySQL server during query de la base de datos de WordPress para la consulta SELECT option_value FROM bio_options WHERE option_name = 'embed_autourls' LIMIT 1 realizada por require('wp-blog-header.php'), require_once('wp-load.php'), require_once('wp-config.php'), require_once('wp-settings.php'), do_action('plugins_loaded'), call_user_func_array, Jetpack::load_modules, require('/plugins/jetpack/modules/shortcodes.php'), jetpack_load_shortcodes, include('/plugins/jetpack/modules/shortcodes/youtube.php'), get_option
[Mon Aug 11 17:50:25.928911 2014] [:error] [pid 11226] [client 127.0.0.1:46620] Error Lost connection to MySQL server during query de la base de datos de WordPress para la consulta SELECT option_value FROM wp_options WHERE option_name = 'akismet_comment_nonce' LIMIT 1 realizada por require('wp-load.php'), require_once('wp-config.php'), require_once('wp-settings.php'), include_once('/plugins/akismet/akismet.php'), get_option, W3_Db->query, W3_DbCache->query, W3_DbCallUnderlying->query, W3_Db->query, W3_DbProcessor->query, W3_Db->default_query
[Mon Aug 11 17:50:35.154185 2014] [:error] [pid 11173] [client 127.0.0.1:46589] PHP Fatal error:  Unknown: Cannot use output buffering in output buffering display handlers in Unknown on line 0
[Mon Aug 11 17:50:35.410068 2014] [:error] [pid 11644] [client 127.0.0.1:46578] PHP Fatal error:  Unknown: Cannot use output buffering in output buffering display handlers in Unknown on line 0
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You have two main options...

1) You can spend countless hours reviewing the queries that WordPress is creating based upon your theme and all the plugins you use and then optimizing them until the problem no longer occurs (which may or may not be feasible depending upon your hosting environment).

-- or --

2) Install something like WP Super Cache ( https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-super-cache/ ) so that the database isn't being hit that hard. It's basically a full page cache that will eliminate DB access for the type of stress you are putting it under. It's even easy enough to deactivate for when you are not scanning if you prefer that. Make sure to preload the cache before running the scan from Woorank.

Comment: I have https://wordpress.org/plugins/w3-total-cache/ installed. And nothing changes when I enable/disable this plugin.

Comment: W3TC does not use page caching by default. You have to set it up to do it. It also doesn't do it as effectively as WP Super Cache. Try verifying that you have Page Cache enabled in W3TC. Also, you could disable that and try WP Super Cache as an experiment.

Comment: No way. I've tried WP Super Cache, but still get the same error.